# After a button is tapped, see if it was tapped again?

Tags: swift

So in Swift, you make your Outlets and actions, so far all good. Then in the action, I have a button placed inside and when it's tapped the label changes strings. Is there anyway to repeat the process like, for one tap says "You tapped it" and then if you tap it again it'll say "You tapped it Again?" and so on and so on. Thanks for the Help!

```
@IBAction func Button(_ sender: Any) {
    if(Button.isTouchInside){
        Lable2.text="You Tapped The Button!!!"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer. Also, if you are using IB - as seen by your IBAction - and triggering your action on .touchUpInside, why are you adding a check in your code? Just make the sender be a UIButton!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a variable that holds a counter.

```
private var buttonTapCount = 0

@IBAction func buttonTap(_ sender: Any) {
    buttonTapCount += 1
    if buttonTapCount == 1 {
        Lable2.text="You Tapped The Button!!!"
    }
    else if buttonTapCount == 2 {
        Lable2.text="You tapped it Again!!!"
    }
    else {
        Lable2.text="You tapped it \(buttonTapCount) times!!!"
    }
}
```